# bash exit with most of the native commands

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash

Whenever I run a command like "autocomplete (tab)", `grep`, `which`, etc, bash window is closed without any warning.

Before this happens, I was playing with the `trap` command to create a script to handle process failures in a screen session, but I did not really change anything. I am not sure if that has anything to do with this.

Any suggestion on how to track what is happening?

Comment: Are you using `set -e`? What's the output of `echo "$-"`

Comment: @glennjackman I don't know if that is set by default somewhere, but I have not set it in my bashrc. The output of `echo "$-"` is `ehimuBHs`

Comment: That "e" means you have `set -e` which means your interactive shell session will exit for any non-zero exit status. Hunt around in your dotfiles for where that is set.

Comment: @glennjackman ahhh I had one script to run in my `bashrc`, which had `set -eu` Thanks for the tip. Saved me tons of time to hunt around to find the cause.